# Add a progress bar percentage while a datadrigview is loading the columns and rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I need help in making my progress bar to work while loading a datadridview because depending of the data sometimes takes 15 to 30 seconds to load and I want the user to see a progress bar letting them know is loading and wait until the progress bar reaches %100. my database table has 11 columns when loading to the datagridview. Please review it not sure if my datarow is setup correcly?

Also after running the program I am getting this error

error InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. also where I need to put my connectionString?

Here is the code

```
private void bgnWorker_LoadingForm_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: query your database
            // for easier reading I assume that your query-result has only one column
            //string query = @"Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus";
            //** did you strip your sql-execution-code? have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx


            var queryResult = new List<object>();
            bgnWorker_LoadingForm.ReportProgress(10);

            var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            // TODO: create matching columns for your query-result in the datatable
            // https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx
            // Create new DataTable and DataSource objects. 

            // Declare DataColumn and DataRow variables.
            DataColumn column;
            DataRow row;
            DataView view;

            // Create new DataColumn, set DataType, ColumnName, and add to DataTable.    
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            column.ColumnName = "invoice";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create second column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            column.ColumnName = "shipment";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create third column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            column.ColumnName = "Project";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create fourth column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
            column.ColumnName = "invoiceDateTB";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create fifth column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
            column.ColumnName = "CreatedDate";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create sixth column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            column.ColumnName = "typeName";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create seventh column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            column.ColumnName = "statusName";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create eighth column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(decimal);
            column.ColumnName = "total";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create ninth column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            column.ColumnName = "import_status";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create tenth column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(DateTime); 
            column.ColumnName = "Time_Completed";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            // Create eleventh column. 
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            column.ColumnName = "ERROR_DESCRIPTION";
            table.Columns.Add(column);



            for (var i = 0; i < queryResult.Count; i++)
            {
                var progress = 10 + (int)((float)i / queryResult.Count) * 90;
                bgnWorker_LoadingForm.ReportProgress(progress);
                //** dont know whats going on here
                //** but normally you should iterate your data-reader here and transfer the data of your query result to the created row... like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx
                row = table.NewRow();
                row["invoice"].ToString();
                row["shipment"].ToString();
                row["Project"].ToString();
                row["invoiceDateTB"] = typeof(DateTime);
                row["CreatedDate"] = typeof(DateTime);
                row["typeName"].ToString();
                row["statusName"].ToString();
                row["total"] = typeof(decimal);
                row["import_status"].ToString();
                row["Time_Completed"] = typeof(DateTime);
                row["ERROR_DESCRIPTION"].ToString();

                table.Rows.Add(row);

                // TODO: add the row data to the table
                // same link as before: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx
            }

            //**begin: move this stuff to worker completed
            // Create a DataView using the DataTable. . 
            view = new DataView(table);
            //**end

            // Set a DataGrid control's DataSource to the DataView.
            dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = view;

            e.Result = table;
        }

        private void bgnWorker_LoadingForm_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable table = (System.Data.DataTable)e.Result;
            // TODO: Check for errors
            // TODO: Assign the table to your grid
            // TODO: unlock your ui, hide progress dialog
        }

        private void bgnWorker_LoadingForm_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: update your progress dialog/progressbar, f.e.
            prgBar_DataGridViewLoading.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bgnWorker_LoadingForm.IsBusy) return;
            bgnWorker_LoadingForm.RunWorkerAsync();
            // TODO: lock your ui, show progress dialog or progressbar...
        }
```

Comment: That's two questions and a code review request. For the error see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: what I really need is the progress bar to work while loading the datagridview